# ArrayAdapter getView method trigger only first element

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I try to use ListFragment to create a list.I created custom array adapter for listfragment. I can see only first item on my activiy When I launch my project.But I've noticed when I drag and drop fist item I can see second item on one line.You can see below my fragment layout and list item layout.Also I attached my custom adapter class.Thanks in advance.

**Fragment layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
    android:name="com.example.fragment.MenuListFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**List item layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="4dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/makel_icon"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_mainMenuImages"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgMenu"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**My custom array adapter**

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MainMenuInfo> {

private List<MainMenuInfo> menuList;
private Context context;
private int layoutResourceID;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID, List<MainMenuInfo> menuList) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, menuList);

    this.context = context;
    this.menuList = menuList;
    this.layoutResourceID = layoutResourceID;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return menuList.size();
}

@Override
public MainMenuInfo getItem(int position) {

    return menuList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return menuList.get(position).get_ID();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, null);
    }

    MainMenuInfo menu = menuList.get(position);

    ImageView imgMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMenu);

    if (menu.getImageName() != null) {

        int r = view.getResources().getIdentifier(menu.getImageName(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        if (r > 0) {
            imgMenu.setImageResource(r);
        }
    }

    TextView txtMenu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMenu);

    txtMenu.setText(menu.getMenuName());

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: can you scroll your list up and down?

Comment: When I scroll on the first item I can see second item.I can see only one item on activity.

Comment: Change the orientation of your fragment `LinearLayout` to be `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Please clarify what is your problem? Are you saying that your listview only shows one item? In that case, it might be an issue with your ArrayList that you use when you define setAdapter.

Comment: Ok my listview only shows one item.I've noticed when i scrool on first item i can see second item.but i can see only one item on activity

Comment: That doesn't clarify the problem.  How many items are suppose to show vs how many are actually showing in the listview.

Comment: Of course more than one item should be.If my listview has a single item Why do i say my listview shows one item? Listview must show 5 item but it shows only first item. I can see second item when i scrool on first item. It shows other items on a row when i scroll  listview.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved.There is no error in the above code.My fault enter incorrect value in the setDividerHeight property.Therefore my listview can not show other items.Thanks.